# Sound stops working when function's added

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When I add EndGame();
The sound stops playing when the game ends.
If I remove the function, the sound plays fine.
I tried adding the gover.Play to EndGame, but that didn't work either.
This bug doesn't really make sense to me as to why it's happening.
Happens in both Editor and on live device.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        AudioSource[] aSources = GetComponents<AudioSource> ();
        perfecthit = aSources [0]; // Works
        gover = aSources [1]; // Works without EndGame()
        miss = aSources [2]; // Works
        gover.Play ();
        EndGame ();// Adding this makes gover.Play stop working
    }
}
    private void EndGame()
    {
        Social.ReportScore (scoreCount, "--", (bool success) => {
            //SUCCESS or FAIL
        });
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("byte", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("byte") + scoreCount / 2);


        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score") < scoreCount)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("score", scoreCount);

        gameOver = true;
        endPanel.SetActive (true);
        theStack[stackIndex].AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        stack.SetActive (false);
        demoObj.SetActive (true);
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen in the Editor too or just on Android? Please comment the ` Social.ReportScore ` line of code then tell me if it is still happening

Comment: @Programmer Still happens. And it's in Editor and on my live device.

Comment: Can you zip the project and update somewhere then provide a link here. I think that something else is happening that I can't see. You can remove all your graphics file and important files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that it stops playing due to the `AudioSource` no longer being available.

Inside the `EndGame()` you are setting `stack.SetActive (false);`. If this `AudioSource` is attached to the object, then it will be no longer available. Especially considering you are re-obtaining your `AudioSources` At least 30 times a second!

With that I would also like to advice you to move your audio logic outside of the [Update](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate) and maybe look into using the [Start, or awake](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/awake-and-start) instead

Comment: Thank you, I totally overlooked that.